# neo4j cypher: stacking nodes from sequential query results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Considering the existence of three types of nodes in a db, connected by the schema

```
(a:a)-[ra:madeWithB {ra.qty}]->(b:b)-[rb:madeWithC {rb.qty}]->(c:c)
```

with the user being able to have connection with each one of these types.

```
(user)-[:has {qty}]->(a:a)
(user)-[:has {qty}]->(b:b)
(user)-[:has {qty}]->(c:c)
```

What would be the best way to query the database to return a list of all the nodes the user :has, considering that when he :has an `(a)` then in the result the associated `(b)` and `(c)` should also be returned after having multiplied their qty field?

Real world example: a user buys three IKEA fully furnished rooms (nodes `a`). The db knows what furniture's in them (`b` nodes) and what parts are needed for those items (nails & stuff, `c` nodes). The user also buys some other random furniture (ie: some more `b` nodes, without being connected to any `a` but being connected to more `c`) and some extra spare nails and other parts (ie: some more `c` nodes, not connected to any `b`).

So - knowing the list of `a` and additional `b` and `c` - print the list of all `b` (that will be the sum of those contained in the three rooms + extra) and `c` (that will be the parts needed for all the furniture and extra), with its associated qty.

**NOTE: consider arbitrary length queries not to be an option when matching nodes.**

Comment: Can you give us an example graph create script (or console link/gist), as well as your expected output?

Comment: I don't. I added a real world example to better explain the situation. If the problem still seems unclear, please tell me how's that so that I can fix the description.